# Can pew and virtualenvwrapper be used together

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to use virtualenvwrapper or pew.  I've installed them both, wanting to test which is easier for me.  I see they both use the $WORKON_HOME shell variable.  If I use both tools, will they clobber each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they won't clobber one another, any more than one alone will clobber itself. You may see warnings about hooks, but that shouldn't be a big deal. Fundamentally it's virtualenv that does the relevant work, not its wrappers. But I recommend using just [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew/) over virtualenvwrapper. (Here's [why](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/2199506).)